# Windows : unable to connect to epmd (port 4369) on sysName: address (cannot connect to host/port)

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

I have been struggling with starting **rabbitmq** server on my local (Windows 7) system. It was working for last 1.5 months and then suddenly it started giving me troubles since my last restart of the system.

> Error: unable to connect to epmd (port 4369) on sysName: address (cannot connect to host/port)

I added sysName to `/etc/hosts` file and mapped it with 127.0.0.1.
Opened port 4369 in firewall, but to no use.

Please help!!

Comment: Try `netstat -an` at server. Is port 4369 in `LISTEN` state? If yes, try to telnet it from client: `telnet 127.0.0.1 4369`

Comment: This is almost certainly a Windows7 issue. It is probably a good idea to add a windows tag to this -- not many Erlang-only folks are intimate with the details of Windows socket/network/whatever permissions and firewall issues.

Answer (score 2):

You need add your `hostname` and the ip(not 127.0.0.1) to the `/etc/hosts`

Answer (score 0):

I could have something to do with files RabbitMQ uses for detecting currently running servers. Try deleting the directory `%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Roaming` and trying again. But be careful: I'm no RabbitMQ expert, but I guess this may delete important stuff like the database itself, Virtual Hosts, users, etc (but for local development, this saves a lot of headache).